# How to detect Bluetooth activated laptops in range in Windows using C#

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, network-programming, bluetooth

I'm interested in creating a wireless network of laptops using Bluetooth developed in C#.

I want to get the list of Bluetooth activated devices in range ( preferable computers, not dongles, headsets or phones). I don't think I need to use a Bluetooth adapter specific stack coz I have seen Windows searching for Bluetooth devices in range. How can I run such a search in my C# app and list the computers in range?

Please help me to do this, also let me know if my effort is wrong. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a nice C# Bluetooth library available in [32feet.NET](http://32feet.codeplex.com/).

If you have no need for any of the additional features it offers and you wish to do the P/Invoke on your own, documentation can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa362932%28v=vs.85%29.aspx); specifically the [BluetoothFindFirstDevice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa362784%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and [BluetoothFindNextDevice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa362788%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) for device discovery.

Additionally, you can use windows sockets to do device/service discovery. Information on that can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa362941%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

If you wish to specifically filter out types of Bluetooth devices, you will want to look at the ulClassOfDevice field in the [BluetoothDeviceInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa362924%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and very helpful links which im going through now. Is there anyway that I could ask windows to do the search for me and then filter the results through my program? is it possible? Like we can do to get the Printer info etc. Thanks again.